# What is the difference between the Ubuntu ~ directory and / directory?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, directory, dotfiles

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to understand the differences between these two directories. I need to know where node packages, git projects, and dotfiles can be installed to avoid future problems.  Does anybody have a quick layman's answer?

I navigate to each directory in the following ways:

```
cd ~
```

or

```
cd /
```

Under which of these directories should I install my [dotfiles](http://dotfiles.github.io/)?

Under which of these directories should I install my git projects?

I'm using Git Bash but I can't locate the directory on my machine for git checkouts.

Comment: To answer your other question, both your dotfiles and your git projects should go into `~`, which as @user3121023 mentioned is really `/home/username/`, (your home directory, which is where personal stuff generally goes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/directory-tree.html) for the Ubuntu directory tree.  It provides a basic explanation of the hierarchy and purpose of each directory.

`cd /` is taking you to your "top" or `root` level directory.

`cd ~` is taking you to your current user home directory within `/home/` (ex:  `/home/username`).

Typically, you'll want to place your dotfiles in your user home directory (`~/`).  If you look at some of the projects in the link you provided, they suggest this as well.

As for your git projects, those can go wherever you see fit.  I prefer to place them within `~/` but it is really a matter of preference.